# Selecting a list of items, from another list of sub items using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

This is a newbie question: I have these two classes that I needed to get a specific list.

```
 public class Customer
 {
     public string firstname { get; set; }
     public string lastname { get; set; }
     ObservableCollection<Address> { get; set; }
 }

 public class Address
 {
      public string Street { get; set; }
      public string City { get; set; }
 }
```

And I have this test data:

Joe, Doe, 123 Main St, New York City
 
Jane, Doe, 456 Main St, New York City
Donald, Tramp, 1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington DC
Spongebob, Squarepants, 124 Conch Street, Bikini Bottom
Oscar, The Grouch, Sesame Street, Anywhere City
 
Milo, Murphy, Unlucky Street, Swamp City

I want to be able to get all the details of the first name, last name, street and city, where the city is "New York City".

So how do I write a LINQ query for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - your code as is doesn't compile.

Comment: Not sure, but if you want the customers with at least one new york address you could do `customers.Where(c => c.Addresses.Any(a => a.City == "New York"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want all the customers with a "New York City" address and ALL their addresses (hierarchical), you would simply do this:

```
var query = from c in customers
            where c.addresses.Any(a => a.City == "New York City")
            select c;
```

If you indeed want a flattened result set, joining the tables and projection to an anonymous type can be done:

```
var query = from c in customers
            from a in c.addresses
            where a.City == "New York City"
            select new
            {
                c.firstname,
                c.lastname,
                a.City,
                a.Street
            };
```

Comment: How does this help to get the _"street and city, where the city is "New York City""_? Consider a customer is from New York but also from Chicago. Then your approach also returns the chicago-address because you don't filter it

Comment: That gets the customers with at least one new york address, but it seems the OP wants the customer name and the new york addresses flattened out.  So customers with more than one new york address would show up multiple times.  Though the example data doesn't make that very clear.

Comment: The question is quite ambiguous when he wrote "all the details of first name, last name, etc." I translated that to mean all addresses for a customer who has one address which matches the filter.  However, I've provided another example to flatten out the data as @juharr suggested might be the OP's intent.